# Области видимости в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которая выдает ошибку:

```
def func(start):
    count = start

    def test(label):
        print(label, count)
        count += 1

    return test
```

Функция test не может найти переменную count в функции func, почему?

Comment: `nonlocal count` - *The nonlocal keyword is used to work with variables inside nested functions, where the variable should not belong to the inner function.*

Comment: Как только вы внутри функции начинаете менять переменную, она автоматически начинает считаться локальной, если явно не указано другое. А локальная переменная не может быть прочитана раньше, чем записана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, я 100500 раз уже отвечал на подобные вопросы, но могу ещё раз.

Как только вы внутри функции начинаете **менять** переменную, она автоматически начинает считаться **локальной**, если явно не указано другое. А локальная переменная не может быть **прочитана** раньше, чем **записана**.

Вы же пытаетесь напечатать переменную до того, как её меняете. Да и конструкция `count += 1` тоже требует прочитать переменную прежде чем её поменять. Если хотите, чтобы питон понял, что это переменная внешней функции, вы должны её объявить нелокальной, как написал в комментарии entithat.

```
    def test(label):
        nonlocal count # говорим питону, что переменная count не локальная
        print(label, count)
        count += 1
```

Comment: `nonlocal` - вроде `global` только для вложенной функции?

Comment: @Leonid Ну это именно что "не локальная". Но и не глобальная )  В общем, говорит питону искать не в локальных и не в глобальных переменных, а в переменных внешних функции по цепочке.

Comment: Боюсь, что если бы он и не печатал переменную, то `count += 1` все равно бы вызвало ошибку, или я не прав?

Comment: @Leonid А, да. `count += 1` тоже требует прочитать переменную, вот если бы там было `count = 1`, то убирание `print` бы ошибку убрало, а так нет. Чуть поменял ответ )